# Callback for upload progress

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I am using [Dropbox client for Python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dropbox) (actually a [Python 3 version](https://github.com/ewjoachim/dropbox-python-sdk-py3), but I don't think it matters now) to upload some files to my Dropbox. I am also using PyQt4 to have a GUI for this.

Is there a possibility to specify a callback to be called when the file is uploaded to show the user the upload progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, you want to show progress while the file is uploading (on a progressbar or something)?
You probably need [`get_chunked_uploader()`](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs/python#DropboxClient.get_chunked_uploader)

From [API Docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#chunked-upload):

> DESCRIPTION Uploads large files to Dropbox in multiple chunks. Also
>   has the ability to resume if the upload is interrupted. This allows
>   for uploads larger than the /files_put maximum of 150 MB.
>
> Typical usage:
>
> 1) Send a PUT request to /chunked_upload with the first chunk of the file
>   without setting upload_id, and receive an upload_id in return.
>
> 2)Repeatedly PUT subsequent chunks using the upload_id to identify the
>   upload in progress and an offset representing the number of bytes
>   transferred so far.
>
> 3)After each chunk has been uploaded, the server
>   returns a new offset representing the total amount transferred.
>
> ...

Comment: Chunked uploaded is designed for uploading large files. While using it can be a workaround, it adds a lot of complexity to my code. My files a hundred of KB in size (screenshots), but waiting several seconds over a slower connection without a visual feedback is disturbing.

Comment: @warvariuc, OK... But I think you'll find that `chunked_uploader` is the only way you're going to get feedback on upload progress. Also I'm not sure I'd agree that an extra half-dozen lines qualifies as ' a lot of complexity'. If you want visual feedback without it, I'd suggest doing what Windows does and just make it up - pulse a progress bar until `put_file()` completes...